# JupyterLab keeps throwing Name is not defined error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I'm a Python beginner and am trying out JupyterLab. I tried a simple line of code but keep getting an error a NameError message: name 'val' is not defined. I'm using JupyterLab 2.1.3 on a localhost (Win 10 Enterprise). Any help?

[image: JupyterLab - "NameError: name 'val' is not defined"]

Comment: You forgot to run the cell above... the one with `val = 4 + 2 +  4` in it

Answer (score 1):

In the picture, the [] beside your code cell indicates that the cell defining val = ... has not been executed. If you run the cell, [] would change to [2] based on your picture.

Simply put, run the cell above first before running the cell you are having error in now.

Or, you can simply combine them:

```
val = 4+2+4
val
```

Run this and it will give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for helping. I found out that my original line of code was written in Raw mode that's why it showed an error. Setting it to Code mode fixed it. Sorry I didn't capture the entire screen.